# How to control the swap drive (X:\drive) usage?

Tags: windows, networking, swap

I am not really a network administrator but my company has LAN which has around 1500 computers. The offices are located in various geographical locations.

The problem we face is that the use of swap drive. People tend to use swap drive for storing confidential information because it is too easy to use. My question is, Is there any way to allow the usage of swap drive but restrict its usage somehow? What policy should be there regarding its usage (cleaning it every night etc)?

Comment: Where do you imagine people will exchange confidential data when you remove this facility?

Comment: I guess creating folder on their own computer and sharing it to other ones would be an option (just not as convenient).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is still vague, but I;m going to take a shot at it.  Your company has a system which mounts a drive on login for every user in the company.  You refer to it as the "swap" drive.  It's read/write by anyone, and it's expected usage is a quick and easy way for people to share files (userA drags a file to X:\, calls or IMs userB and tells them to "check the swap drive for FileName").  This isn't really a product, it's just a set of login rules mounting a share automatically at boot.

OK so far?

So your problem is that people have been storing inappropriate content (like, say, HR records) that shouldn't be viewable by everyone, and using the drive for longer term storage instead of treating it as ephemeral.

Still on track?

If those assumptions are correct, run a job every four hours that deletes any file that is older than four hours.  Document this procedure in IT policy and distribute it to your users.  Also document the proper document type and punishment for using the drive inappropriately (which you'll probably never use, but you have to get it on paper).  As for monitoring for those files,   that's a harder problem.  There might be hueristics, but you'll probably see them or have them reported to you (you know about it now, right?).

Or, I've failed to read your mind and I'm entirely wrong =).

Comment: Would have been my guess as well.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your point. Its more of a management issue than a technical one..

Answer (score 1):

You could remove ListDirectory permission from everyone, thus only ppl having the exact path to the file will be able to access it.